# Formatting and redirecting users (w/ jQuery UI Autocomplete)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-autocomplete

I'm new to jQuery and Stack Overflow. I'm doing my school project and have implemented the basic autocomplete search to work on my group's ASP.NET web application. I went along with this guide: http://www.magic-dev.com/autocomplete-textbox-aspnet-database.htm.

I can search for names (taken from the database), but what I'm trying to do is to allow the user to select the name (on clicking a name) from the result, and redirect them to a profile page (e.g. *profile.aspx?id=25*).

I have searched on Stack Overflow and came across [Redirecting users on select from autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503793/redirecting-users-on-select-from-autocomplete). Tried implementing the codes on that question, but to no avail.

The current result for the search box is something like this (format **[user's ID]-[Name]**):

```
25-Dennis Ferrell
```

I do not want to display the ID in the result, but only show the name. The ID was added into it because I wanted to use the ID for *profile.aspx?id=25*.

** **EDIT 1** **

I read that `formatItem` and `formatResult` are both depreciated from jQuery UI (http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/06/autocomplete-migration-guide). So right now, I got the code to redirect the user on click, but the format is still `25-Dennis Ferrell`.

Here's my updated code:

```
       $('#<%= searchMenu.ClientID %>').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "PredictiveSearch.asmx/GetAllNames",
                    data: "{'nameKeyword':'" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    }
                });
            }, 
            select: function (event, data) {
                window.location = "profile.aspx?id=" + data.item.value.split("-")[0];
            }
        });
```

Can anyone help me out with the formatting? Just want to remove the `25-` from `25-Dennis Ferrell` and use the `25` to redirect the user via the ID.

** **EDIT 2** **

I tried doing this:

```
success: function (data) {
    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
        return item.split("-")[1];
    }));
}
```

The result will be `Dennis Ferrell`, but the `25` can't be passed into the `select:` function (which is needed for redirecting the user).

Comment: What's not working exactly? I am pretty sure your `split` code is correct if `ui.item.value` is what you way it is.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker I've updated the question (see **EDIT 2**).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Glad to see you finally posting here :) Instead of adding "Solved" to your title, you can mark your own answer accepted after a certain period of time by clicking the hollow checkmark on its left — that's how we indicate solved questions here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I got it to split. The result in the search box will show `Dennis Ferrell` while the `select:` function got the ID value of `25` in. Not the best answer, I think, but still, here's the code for the `success:` function:

```
success: function (data) {
    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
        return {
            id: item.split("-")[0],
            value: item.split("-")[1],
        }
    }));
}
```

And the code for the `select:` function:

```
select: function (event, data) {
    //use data.item.value if want to get the name [Dennis Ferrell]
    window.location = "profile.aspx?id=" + data.item.id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should get the id from ui.item.id within the select function.

```
location.href = "profile.aspx?id=" + ui.item.id
```

hope it helps

Comment: On selecting the result, it doesn't redirect me to the page at all.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
window.location = "page.aspx?userid="+ui.item.id;
```

Comment: Does not work. On clicking/selecting the result, it does nothing.